# Why can't UltiSnips use python while 'python' is enabled?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I want to use the [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) plugin in Vim 7.4 under Windows 10.

When enter `:version` I see that python is there, but when I launch gVim, it says in a dialog box

```
UltiSnips requires py >= 2.7 or py3`
```

How can I make my system compatible with UltiSnips (e. g. find a Vim distro with support for Python 2.7 or 3) ?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4718183/4194289) python should be supported by default but you need to install python on your system. (Even if Vim support its usage, it can not use it if it is not installed)

Comment: Thanks. Which Python is better - 2.7.x or 3? I need Vim to develop in Java/Kotlin as explained in [this tutorial](http://www.lucianofiandesio.com/vim-configuration-for-happy-java-coding).

Comment: That's a question that I can't really answer. Python 3 is the new version of python and it provides some new features but python 2 is still widely used and I'm not really a python expert :-) I'd say that it depends on your needs, here your needs are UltiSnips and they don't recommend a particular version of python so take the one you want and remember that if you need it you can have several versions of python installed on your system without conflicts.

Comment: If installing python do solve your problem, let us know: I can make an answer or you can answer your own post to make it useful to other users :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that your Vim setup supports python, but python is not installed on your system.

When Vim has the `'python'` and/or `'python3'` features enabled that means that it provides an interface to interact with python code: you can make Vim to ask the system to execute a python statement or a whole python code.

Even if the interface is enabled, Vim is not a python compiler/executer: you still need to install them on your system so that Vim can make a call to these tools. See [this page](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) to get the executable to install python.

---

In the comments OP also had a question about which version of python (python2 or python3) to install:

Here python was needed to make UltiSnips working, as UltiSnips doesn't recommend a specific version I'd recommend to install whatever version you want, both should work. Remember that it is possible to install several version of python on the same system.